# Why are there Asian subtitles in some renderings of these shots?

Tags: star-trek, production

In the Star Trek original series episode "The Naked Time", there is a short sequence in which Spock makes his way from the bridge to engineering, encountering a delirious crewman along the way. A few seconds after the encounter (about 29:10), we see that the crewman has written "Love Mankind" on the wall in red paint. There is a later scene where Kirk enters a turbolift and as the doors close, we see "Sinner Repent" written on the inside (about 43:50).

In the version I was watching (16:9 remaster with CGI effects viewed on Canada's Sci-Fi channel), subtitles appear in an Asian script (Japanese, I think). There are no subtitles other than accompanying the red paint. The same shots appears in the 4:3 version available to me on Netflix, without the subtitles. The soundtrack seems entirely consistent with a North American English release. Is this a "known" mistake in the remaster? Is this some sort of bootleg that found its way into the library of a mainstream cable channel?

[image]

Comment: Time hack please, and I'll check the Paramount + version.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've added times, but from the Netflix 4:3 version

Comment: The script *is* Japanese, and it says "love humanity' (or "love mankind"). That is, 人類を愛せ. 人類 (humanity) を (object particle) 愛せ (command form of 愛す, to love). It's a very direct command (no kudasai, in other words), which I suppose might fit with the "rough" nature of graffiti.

Comment: Thanks for the time hack. The text does not appear in the (remastered) version of the episode currently available on Paramount+.

Comment: Bootleg was also my first thought. It's been known to happen.